# Couldn't push code from WSL terminal to github

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-access, git-push

So, I am trying to push the code from my local machine to GitHub from the WSL terminal, but I am not able to do that; every time I run command `git push -u origin main` I get this as error:

```
Enumerating objects: 3825, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3825/3825), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2621/2621), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3825/3825), 16.06 MiB | 180.77 MiB/s, done.
Total 3825 (delta 840), reused 3783 (delta 822), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (840/840), done.
remote: fatal: did not receive expected object aa35c21bf221e29f6e6b86771c2dcad6c20d151b
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack failed
To https://github.com/monishkajha17/my-first-nft.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/monishkajha17/my-first-nft.git'
```

I tried to set remote access again by using the commands

```bash
git remote add origin https://github.com/monishkajha17/my-first-nft.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

But, still it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when there is a mismatch between the local and remote repository. It can be caused by various things, such as network errors during push, repository corruption, etc.

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot the issue:

- Check your network connection: Ensure you have a stable internet connection.
- Update Git: Sometimes outdated Git clients can cause problems, so make sure you're running a recent version of Git. You can check your version with git --version and update Git if needed.
- Try a fresh clone: Clone the repository into a new directory and manually merge your changes:

[image: This creates a fresh copy of the repository, which could resolve any issues related to a corrupted local repository.]

This creates a fresh copy of the repository, which could resolve any issues related to a corrupted local repository.

- Git GC: The git gc command can help clean up unnecessary files and optimize your local repository.

[image]

- Finally check for repository corruption: Run git fsck to verify the integrity of your Git database.

[image]

Remember to back up your code before taking any steps, especially when dealing with potential repository corruption.

Comment: still the code is not pushed into it the repository got sub-repo in it. 
I tried all the above stated but, they worked but the code didn't push only a submodule does, it made a empty commit but I made two changes in file

Comment: And I tried with the refreshed terminal and everything, and made a new empty repo in my terminal, installed some dependencies in them and add some code changes within it. Tried to push it, but still got the same error.

Comment: Reach out to Git Hub then. There might be a repository issue that is disabling remote access from your account.

Comment: Please do not use an AI to write your answers for you. We expect answers to be in your own words, not plagiarised from an AI.